# Is it possible to force Ubuntu to give "total" priority to a task?

Tags: ubuntu

I am writing an assignment for students in a second year programming course (that is, I am the instructor, they are the students). The goal is to write a faster algorithm than mine, as measured by the Linux "time" command. However, the run speed of the code depends on what's going on in the background. I have Ubuntu desktop (I believe it is 20.04) and it is running natively (not VM). Is it possible to run a command that tells Ubuntu "this is the only process that matters" or "this process gets the absolute highest safe priority" or something?

Some extra facts:

1. The students are limited to using a single thread, but that's basically the only limitation
2. This computer is not networked and it is essentially a jail cell for the students to come and test their code. I'd prefer if they didn't, but are technically free to screw it up with bad commands.
3. The consequence of (2) is that I am OK running student code as super user (!)

**Edit: I am intentionally using an inefficient algorithm. My runtime is 60 minutes, so if the computer is doing something that takes a few minutes to run anyway that may slow their stuff down. However, I do expect they should be able to reduce the runtime to under a minute.

Comment: I went looking for an Ubuntu equivalent for Windows 'Realtime', thinking maybe you could `nice` it to similar, but found this instead - https://ubuntu.com/blog/real-time-linux-qa I have no clue if it could be what you need.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: be wary. if the app doesn't exit gracefully, and you don't let the OS run other threads, your system will turn into a stone. you'd have to pull the plug to stop it. my first guess is that you won't find somthing that does exactly what you describe for exactly this reason.